# http post request in Server Side Javascript

Tags: javascript, curl, ssjs

I'm trying a http post request to get an access token. In curl I got it working like this:

```
curl -X POST 'https://www.completeurl.com' -H 'Authorization: Basic base64encodedstroing=' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d grant_type=client_credentials
```

and I get a respons in json:
    {"access_token":"tokenvalue","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":3600}

So far so good, but now I have to do it in ServerSide Javascript:

```
var accessTokenUrl = "https://www.completeurl.com";
var data = "grant_type=client_credentials";
var accessHeaderNames = ["Authorization","Content-Type"];

var apiKey = "mykey";
var apiSecret = "mysecret";
var totalKey = apiKey + ":" + apiSecret;

// we need to Base64 encode the key and secret
var base64encoded = Base64Encode(totalKey);
var tokenMoney = "Basic" + " " + base64encoded;

var accessHeaderNames = ["Authorization","Content-Type"];
var accessHeaderValues = [tokenMoney, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"];
```

How should I put this all together in something like this:
    var accessTokenReply = HTTP.Post(accessTokenUrl,accessHeaderNames,accessHeaderValues);

where can I put the -d party from the curl version that works?

Comment: That's just body data you should post. Read the docs of the HTTP lib you're using on how to actually do that.

Comment: Are you using Netscape Enterprise Server? (Or some other tool for running SSJS)?

Comment: I'm using SSJS in salesforce marketing